# Using Lean to prove theorems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I'm using lean to prove theorems and I'm still getting the hang of things. This is what I have so far.

((P → Q) → P) → P

I know that the theorem is true and can be proven.

This is where I get to and get stuck.

1. assume pqp,
2. apply pqp,
3. assume p,

At which point I'm left with

PQ: Prop

pqp: (P → Q) → P

p: P

⊢ Q

I can't work out how to prove this given that I feel like i need to break up pqp into something smaller but I haven't worked out how to yet.

Comment: I think you will do far better to post your problem on one of the Lean fora. Perhaps their chat site?

Comment: For those who have never heard about Lean like me : https://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/

Comment: Yes you're right you need to breakup pqp into $\lnot(P \to Q) \lor P$ type via the definition of material conditional, then use $\lor$ E rule if you're working with a natural deduction system. And you may break as such again in the case analysis of $\lnot(P \to Q)$...

Comment: @mohottnad ok thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prove this in "vanilla Lean", since Lean uses intuitionist logic. You require classical logic in order to prove this theorem, since in the case that $Q = \bot$, we can prove $\neg \neg P \to P$ using the claim that $((P \to Q) \to P) \to P$. The principle you're trying to prove is Pierce's Law, a well-known equivalent of classical logic.

The proof, in English, should go something like this.

We first suppose $((P \to Q) \to P)$. We now prove $P$ by contradiction.

Suppose $\neg P$.

We now prove $P \to Q$. For suppose $P$. We have both $P$ and $\neg P$; contradiction. Therefore, $Q$. $P \to Q$ has been proved.

Since $P \to Q$ and also $((P \to Q) \to P)$, we have proved $P$. We have both $P$ and $\neg P$, which is a contradiction.

In Lean:

```
section
variables (P Q : Prop)
open classical

example (h : (P → Q) → P) : P :=
   by_contradiction (assume h1 : ¬ P,
     have h2 : P → Q, from (assume h3 : P, show Q, from false.elim (h1 h3)), 
     have h3 : P, from h h2,
     show false, from h1 h3).

end
```